# localhost gives undefined constant

Tags: php, localhost

I have configured eclipse PHP developers with Egit and Bitbucket through [this](http://crunchify.com/how-to-configure-bitbucket-git-repository-in-you-eclipse/), when I run my localhost and when I want to check it out I get this error:

> ( ! ) Notice: Use of undefined constant FOO - assumed 'FOO' in
>   C:\wamp\www\SWEBSITES\TM\website\config.php on line 24

this is my config.php

```php
<?php   
    $base_config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/s-cms/';

    $base_config['db_host'] = 'localhost';
    $base_config['db_name'] = 's-cms';
    $base_config['db_user'] = 'root';
    $base_config['db_pass'] = '';

    $base_config['theme']   = 'basic';

    $base_config['allow_5_4'] = false;

    $base_config['salt']            = 'F5:~{`r~/4(]7*hYUctxJ |hz:F^|q:<t.B4S=-_y1DnDQ7rq#~oG& PVq/q? :e';
    $base_config['encryption_key']  = FOO
    //$base_config['session_salt']  = 'b[}XS=/%d^H<E?Ja4o.cT`pGrN2.z|Q*Jlu|Ci|H$v-ToYU}*RM11;<zk/Sp+SLF';
    //$base_config['session_key']       = '%*G;m~6E[X9,G=9]/]8h{ Muoxv%U]&i=0379E]l]/|A|O fD%jbZc3Z{WVD;It3';
?>
```

Then I changed my config and I tried to define something for FOO so I changed it into this:

`$base_config['encryption_key'] = 'FOO';`

now when I visit localhost I see :

> Failed to connect to database

where could this error be from??

Comment: uh, define a value for `FOO`?

Comment: I guess `FOO` needs to be enclosed with quotes: `$base_config['encryption_key']  = "FOO"`. In your given config, `FOO` receives no value otherwise

Comment: @eckes I already did this, when I go to localhost I get this error: Failed to connect to database

Answer (score 1):

Its about this row `$base_config['encryption_key']  = FOO`

You need to put it inside quotes *(to remove the Notice)* and close it with a semicolen *(to remove any errors that will come because of not closing it right)*.

`$base_config['encryption_key']  = 'FOO';`

---

**Edit after comment:** 
Add an key instead of FOO,, because FOO is an placeholder (probably from a tutorial). Or leave it empty. `$base_config['encryption_key']  = '';`

Comment: Than add the enqryption key instead of `FOO`,, because `FOO` is an placeholder (probably from a tutorial)

Comment: agan it didnt work and i still get the failed to connect to DB!!

Comment: Do you need to add an password? OR do you have activated your database with wamp?

Comment: I have doanload wamp, and when I go to my phpmyadmin I dont have any password, maybe I have to change things in wamp, config??

Comment: Oki I fixed hat but now I get this error: 
( ! ) Fatal error: Incorrect base_url: 'http://localhost/sg-cms/' does not match 'http://localhost/SWEBSITES/t_m/website/index.php' in C:\wamp\www\SWEBSITES\t_m\website\includes\routing.php on line 277

Comment: Sorry but that will be a new question to ask instead of trying to achieve it trough comment writing. Good luck!